# jlabel setLineWrap - outgoing text

Tags: java, swing

How to setLineWrap, I'm according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap%28boolean%29

but how I can setLineWrap to jlabel, I have something like this:

```
String a = "text (...)";
JLabel label = new JLabel(a);
```

but my text is leaving

I mean:

JLabel:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaxxxxxxx where a is text and x is text that disappeared

JTextArea:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

aaaaaaa

Answer (score 1):

There is no setLineWrap method in JLabel. But if you set HTML to the JLabel you can overcome this.

```
JLabel l = new JLabel("<html><p>line 1</p><p>line 2</p></html>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use a JTextField and make it readonly to look like a Label. When you make the text field readonly, the long text can be scrollable using keyboard.

```
JTextField txtLabel = new JTextField();
txtLabel.setEditable(false)
txtLabel.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaxxxxxxx");
```

If you want the text to wrap you may want to use the JTextArea by making it readonly with a label look and feel.